# Upload to S3 from React Native with AWS Amplify

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm trying to upload an image to S3 from React Native using Amplify.  I am able to upload a text file SUCCESSFULLY.  But not an image.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, Image} from 'react-native';
import {identityPoolId, region, bucket} from '../auth';
import image from '../assets/background.png';
import Amplify, {Storage} from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {identityPoolId,region},
    Storage : {bucket,region}
})

const upload = () => {
    Storage.put('logo.jpg', image, {contentType: 'image/jpeg'})
        .then(result => console.log('result from successful upload: ', result))
        .catch(err => console.log('error uploading to s3:', err));
}

const get = () => {   //this works for both putting and getting a text file
    Storage.get('amir.txt')
        .then(res => console.log('result get', res))
        .catch(err => console.log('err getting', err))
}

export default function ImageUpload(props) {

    return (
        <View style={{alignItems : 'center'}}>
            <Image style={{width: 100, height: 100}} source={image} />
            <Text>Click button to upload above image to S3</Text>
            <Button title="Upload to S3" onPress={upload}/>
            <Button title="Get from S3" onPress={get}/>
        </View>
    )

}
```

the error message is:

```
error uploading to s3: [Error: Unsupported body payload number]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the react-native-aws3 library to upload the images to S3.
I wish it could be more straight forward to find answers with how to upload an image directly using AWS amplify, but it wasn't working.  So here is what I did:

(the wrapper of this function is a React Component.  I'm using ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker', Permissions from 'expo-permissions' and Constants from 'expo-constants' to set up the Image uploading from the Camera Roll)

```
import {identityPoolId, region, bucket, accessKey, secretKey} from '../auth';
import { RNS3 } from 'react-native-aws3';



async function s3Upload(uri) {

      const file = {
               uri,
               name : uri.match(/.{12}.jpg/)[0],
               type : "image/png"
      };

        const options = { keyPrefix: "public/", bucket, region, 
        accessKey, secretKey, successActionStatus: 201}

        RNS3.put(file, options)
            .progress(event => {
                console.log(`percentage uploaded: ${event.percent}`);
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 201) {
                    console.log('response from successful upload to s3:', 
                    res.body);
                    console.log('S3 URL', res.body.postResponse.location);
                    setPic(res.body.postResponse.location);

                } else {
                    console.log('error status code: ', res.status);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('error uploading to s3', err)
            })
}

const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes : ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing : true,
            aspect : [4,3],
            quality : 1
        });

        console.log('image picker result', result);

        if (!result.cancelled) {
            setImage(result.uri);
            s3Upload(result.uri);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your secret key is exposed here - how did you get around the obvious security issue of having to add a secret key to the app itself?

Comment: I don't see the secret key exposed here.  The key is located in a local .env file, not here.  unless I'm  missed it by mistake

Comment: How does it get from the `env` to the `options` hash you use above?

I mean "exposed" as in you have to add the credentials to the actual code you load onto peoples phones. You would need that secret key to be readable and in plain text to add it here:
    `const options = ...etc`

To avoid adding the secret key to your repo or the code that lands up on peoples phones you would need something like an s3 pre-signed url strategy. i.e 

have a look at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node ... as a base example. Unless I am completely missing something here.

Comment: Hi I followed the same but I'm getting this error

{"headers": {}, "status": 0, "text": "Stream Closed"}

any help will be approciated

Comment: @user1230795. What you said makes total sense.  I would probably need to use the pre-signed url strategy.  Will do in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In our recent Single Page Application (SPA) style web application, from React, we used "S3 Signed URLs" for efficient upload/download of files and I felt this has resulted in a cleaner design as compared to direct upload/download.

What is the back-end services implemented in?

Comment: Yeah, I did the same with my mobile app. The upload and download are much faster and the code is cleaner. But it doesn't help him at all.

Comment: We wanted to upload directly from the front end to S3.  and then send back the URL of the object to our backend, which is implemented in ```node/express```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on your node server, save it the URL and send it back to the app. 
It'll look like:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({accessKeyId:'XXXXXXXXXXXX', secretAccessKey:'YYYYYYYYYYYY', region:'REGION'});

var params = {Bucket: 'yourBucket', Key: 'your_image/your_image.jpg', ContentType: 'image/jpeg'};
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
    // send it back to the app
});
```

On the app side you'll have something like:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      Alert.aler("Upload", "Done");
    } else {
     Alert.aler("Upload", "Failed");
    }
  }
}
xhr.open('PUT', presignedUrlReceiveFromServer)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', fileType)
xhr.send({ uri: imageFilePath, type: fileType, name: imageFileName })
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks.  That is fine, but I wanted to keep it simple and do it from the front end directly.  I just don't understand why I can upload a text file using my method, but not an image file.  It's something probably small I'm missing.